# Not redirecting to chekout sucess

Tags: checkout

When i complete credit card payment as a guest , it is not redirecting to checkout success page. It says "invalid order". It made mix up for my clients. How can i fix it ? I don't have the same problem when i login account as a member.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code, Some where in your custom module you are trying to fetch the data of registered customer but you are not getting that data while you are placing order as a guest customer.